# How to return multiple image as output results by the for-loop of the function into the main

Tags: matlab

I want to get all the segmented lines image results from my functions into the main, but it only returns the last line of the input image.

Here is the function for line segmentation code:

```
function mat5 = charextract(ipimg)
%%%aa=imread('num_ip.tif');
bb=rgb2gray(ipimg);
cc=imbinarize(bb);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%   SEGMENTATION    %%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[x,y]=size(cc);
ee=sum(cc,2);
mat2=y-ee;
mat3=mat2~=0;
mat4=diff(mat3);
index1=find(mat4);
[q,w]=size(index1);%size of index2 matrix is q*w
kap=1;
lam=1;
while kap<((q/2)+1)%number of loops=number of lines
      k=1;
      mat5=([]);
      for j=(index1(lam)+1):1:index1(lam+1)
         mat5(k,:)=cc(j,:); %store the line segmented matrix
         %aadd{j}=mat5(k,:);
         k=k+1;
      end
        lam=lam+2;   
        kap=kap+1;
        %aa=mat5+1;
        %figure, imshow(mat5);
end
end
```

Here is the main code:

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;
img=imread('num_ip.tif');
img2=charextract(img);
imshow(img2);
```

Comment: If your still having trouble, please paste a sample image into the question and lets see how we can get the program to function correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are clearing the mat5 container every time the while loop runs. If you move it out of the while loop, it should fix the problem.

Edit: The K is also being set to 1 every time the while loop runs. This means after the first iteration of the for loop. K will equal 1 `k=1` and will overwrite your previous data.

```
function mat5 = charextract(ipimg)
%%%aa=imread('num_ip.tif');
bb=rgb2gray(ipimg);
cc=imbinarize(bb);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%   SEGMENTATION    %%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
[x,y]=size(cc);
ee=sum(cc,2);
mat2=y-ee;
mat3=mat2~=0;
mat4=diff(mat3);
index1=find(mat4);
[q,w]=size(index1);%size of index2 matrix is q*w
kap=1;
lam=1;
mat5=([]); % moved out of while loop
k=1;

while kap<((q/2)+1)%number of loops=number of lines

      for j=(index1(lam)+1):1:index1(lam+1)
         mat5(k,:)=cc(j,:); %store the line segmented matrix
         %aadd{j}=mat5(k,:);
         k=k+1;
      end
        lam=lam+2;   
        kap=kap+1;
        %aa=mat5+1;
        %figure, imshow(mat5);
end
end
```

Comment: Still, I got the last line of the input image.

Comment: After moving out the K, it gives the same input image as output without any segmentation of the lines.

Comment: still not getting. need help